# Responsive Form 'Submit' Button - Mobile Version

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm having such a difficult time with this one; i've been racking my brain for hours and am just about to pull my hair out..

I have a form:

```
<div class="inforight-contact">

<form action="contact-sent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
<p>

<label class="input">
<span>Name</span>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="name"/>
</label>
</p>
                  <p>
<label class="input">
<span>Email</span>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="email" />
</label>
</p>


<p>
<label class="input">
<span>Subject</span>
<input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" class="subject" />
</label>
</p> 

<p>
<label for="fileField">Comments:</label>
<label for="Comments"></label>
<textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" class="comments" cols="90" rows="4"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="image" id="submit" class="submit" />
</p>
</form>

</div>
```

This is my responsive CSS:

```
form {
margin-right: 0x;
margin-top: 20px;
        }

form label {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

form .submit {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0px;
            background: #EA5310;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #fff;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            height: 20px;
        }





form input.name,
form input.email,
form input.tel,
form input.subject {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            background: #f3f4f5;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #777;
            outline: none;
            text-align: center;
        }


form input.name:focus,
form input.tel:focus,
form input.email:focus,
form input.subject:focus
            {
                box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #E0E0E0;
                background: #fff;
            }


form textarea.comments {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            background: #f3f4f5;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #777;
            outline: none;
        }


form input.comments:focus
            {
                box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #E0E0E0;
                background: #fff;
            }
```

The problem I have is that the 'Submit' button text won't sit in the center. It sits align:left. It looks fine if I shrink my desktop screen to be mobile size, and if I use something like screenfly or Firefox's Responsive website, but on my mobile it sits aligned to the left and with a white box around the text. This makes it really hard to identify the problem, because I can only see the problem on my mobile. The Firebug application lists all my .css styles and shows that it should sit text-align: center, but it's not. Can anyone see anything I can't? Please let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code :

```
<input type="image" id="submit" class="submit" />
```

by

```
<input type="text" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it would be something simple. Thank you!! I've been pulling my hair out with that one for hours. Much appreciated!

Comment: One more thing: I guess because of how I have my boxes (the value sat inside the box which then disappears when the user clicks) the Submit button now things it's a field to be written. It's because the input now reads input type="text"  Any ideas?

Comment: I've changed the button to be input type="submit" and this has resolved it. However I had changed this originally because it was given me problems with the width (not sitting at 100%). I'll try and resolve that one again though.

Comment: Use the actual syntax for a button: `<button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit>Submit</button>`